# can we have if statement for choosing among bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want one modal to be appear when i click select, I have radio button in first page( Eg, oneway, twoway), so when user clicks on it should go to second page ,when user selects the oneway , the fields corresponding to it should display or else twoway fields, Can i use if Statment for this.?If so how?

Comment: I read your question twice, but I still don't understand it. Perhaps start with shorter sentences?

Comment: I want one modal to be appear ,based on the type of radio button selectd

Comment: Ok. Do you have some code with different types of radio buttons that can be selected? And clearly indicate what you want each to do.

Comment: <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="oneway" id="id_radio" onclick="hide();" />One Way</label>
               <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="roundtrip" id="id_radio3" onclick="show();" />Round Trip</label>  this is my radio button, i am hiding some fileds when clicking on each buttons, when i finally submit my form it will redirect to other page where i have moda, with some fields and calculations displayed i that, as i have different fields for button , calculation will change.

Comment: I realize you're new to StackOverflow, but next time, please put your code in the question, and format it as code.

Comment: See: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods and use `$('#myModal').modal('show')` in the `onclick` of each radio button. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No i already done that.

Comment: why not show your effort and code? or you expect us to write the code for you?

Comment: so considering which radio button is selected i want to display my modal .

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Are you saying: "I want to display a different modal depending on which radio button is selected." or: "I want to display, in my modal, which radio button is selected."?

Comment: I want to display a different modal depending on which radio button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect different modals to each button like this:

```
<label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="oneway" id="id_radio"
         onclick="hide();$('#myModal1').modal('show');" />
  One Way
</label> 
<label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="roundtrip" id="id_radio3"
         onclick="show();$('#myModal2').modal('show');" />
  Round Trip
</label>
```

Notice that clicking on 'One Way' will show modal `#myModal1` while clicking on 'Round Trip' will show modal `#myModal2`.